# repeatedly read Ruby IO until X bytes have been read, Y seconds have elapsed, or EOF, whichever comes first

Tags: ruby, multithreading, io, pipe, named-pipes

I want to forward logs from an IO pipe to an API.  Ideally, there would be no more than e.g. 10 seconds of latency (so humans watching the log don't get impatient).

A naive way to accomplish this would be to use `IO.each_byte` and send each byte to the API as soon as it becomes available, but the overhead of processing a request per byte causes additional latency.

`IO#each(limit)` also gets close to what I want, but if the limit is 50 kB and after 10 seconds, only 20 kB has been read, I want to go ahead and send that 20 kB without waiting for more.  How can I apply both a time and size limit simultaneously?

Comment: wonder if you could just wrap the code in a `Timeout.timeout(y) do` block

Comment: @maxpleaner wow, I was not aware `Timeout` is in a standard library. This approach has a glitch though: the `IO` device will be left in an undetermined state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with.  Simpler solutions still appreciated!

```
def read_chunks(io, byte_interval: 200 * 1024, time_interval: 5)
  buffer = last = nil
  reset = lambda do
    buffer = ''
    last = Time.now
  end
  reset.call
  mutex = Mutex.new
  cv = ConditionVariable.new
  [
    lambda do
      IO.select [io]
      mutex.synchronize do
        begin
          chunk = io.readpartial byte_interval
          buffer.concat chunk
        rescue EOFError
          raise StopIteration
        ensure
          cv.signal
        end
      end
    end,
    lambda do
      mutex.synchronize do
        until io.eof? || Time.now > (last + time_interval) || buffer.length > byte_interval
          cv.wait mutex, time_interval
        end
        unless buffer.empty?
          buffer_io = StringIO.new buffer
          yield buffer_io.read byte_interval until buffer_io.eof?
          reset.call
        end
        raise StopIteration if io.eof?
      end
    end,
  ].map do |function|
    Thread.new { loop { function.call } }
  end.each(&:join)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

A naïve approach would be to use [`IO#each_byte`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/IO.html#method-i-each_byte) *enumerator*.

The contrived, not tested example:

```
enum = io.each_byte
now = Time.now
res = while Time.now - now < 20 do
  begin
    send_byte enum.next
  rescue e => StopIteration
    # no more data
    break :closed
  end 
end
puts "NO MORE DATA" if res == :closed
```

Comment: if I'm understanding correctly, would `send_byte` still generate a request per byte?

Comment: If you want to collect and send data in chunks, just collect inside `while` and `send` afterwards. The goal of the snippet above was to show how to deal with timeouts, not how to send.